# Lightning Datatable Not Pulling in Data

Tags: apex, lightning, soql, lightning-web-components

I've made my first Lightning Web Component and it deploys and displays the column headers I have indicated but it isn't pulling in any data for the related quote line items. It looks like this currently:

[image: Current view of component]

Here is my apex controller to query the records;

```
public with sharing class QuoteLineItemController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<QuoteLineItem> getQuoteLineItems(Id quoteId) {
        return [ SELECT 
        AdditionalNewsletterBrandsDetails__c,Additional_Information__c,Additional_Notes__c,
        Additional_Web_Brands_Details__c,Advice_Brand__c,Brand__c,
        Campaign_Name__c,Company_Sizes__c,Cost_Type__c,CQs__c,CreatedById,CreatedDate,Created_By__c,
        Creative_Format__c,Creative_Sizes__c,Creative_Source__c,Description,Device_Category__c,
        Discount,Display_Google_Form_Reminder__c,Email_Blast_Count_Required__c,Email_Blast_Record_Count__c,
        End_Date__c,Exact_Company_Sizes__c,Exact_Geography__c,Exact_Industries__c,Exact_Job_Titles__c,
        Flight_Dates__c,Frequency_Cap_Count__c,Frequency_Cap_Hours__c,Geography__c,Id,Industries__c,IsDeleted,
        Job_Titles__c,Keywords__c,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,LastReferencedDate,LastViewedDate,
        LineNumber,Line_Item_ID__c,ListPrice,Media_Channels__c,Newsletter_Brands__c,OpportunityLineItemId,
        Potential_Clicks__c,PricebookEntryId,Price_per_Unit__c,Product2Id,Product_Family_Picklist__c,
        Product_Family__c,Product_ID__c,Quantity,Quote_ID__c,Rate_Factor__c,Rate__c,Rejected__c,
        Rejection_Notes__c,Reporting_Platform__c,Sales_Comments__c,ServiceDate,SortOrder,Start_Date_Time__c,
        Subtotal,SystemModstamp,Timeframe_Days__c,Topic_Area__c,TotalPrice,UnitPrice,Web_Brands__c 
            FROM QuoteLineItem
            WHERE Quote_ID__c = :quoteId];

    }
}
```

My HTML file:

```
<template>
    <div style="height: 300px;">
        <lightning-card>
            <template if:true={quotelineitems.data}>
                <lightning-datatable
                    key-field="Id"
                    data={quotelineitems.data}
                    columns={columns}>
                </lightning-datatable>
            </template>
        </lightning-card>
    </div>    
</template>
```

My javascript:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/QuoteLineItem.Id';
import UNITPRICE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/QuoteLineItem.UnitPrice';
import getQuoteLineItems from '@salesforce/apex/QuoteLineItemController.getQuoteLineItems';
const COLUMNS = [
    { label: 'Id', fieldName: 'Id', type: 'text'},
    { label: 'Sales Price', fieldName: 'UnitPrice', type: 'currency' },
];
export default class quoteLineItemDataTableLWC extends LightningElement {
    columns = COLUMNS;
    @wire(getQuoteLineItems)
    quotelineitems;
}
```

And my meta XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="quoteLineItemDataTableLWC">
    <apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightning__Tab</target>
    </targets>

</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Please help! I'm very new to this so any suggestions you can give me would be great!

Comment: Side question: Is the custom field Quote_ID__c intentional in the soql query? QuoteLineItem had a standard QuoteId field.

Answer (score 3):

Your `getQuoteLineItems` method takes a `quoteId` parameter.

Assuming the LWC is on a Quote record page, update your LWC wire call to include this parameter.

```
// Bind the recordId from the record page context
@api recordId;

@wire(getQuoteLineItems, { quoteId: '$recordId' })
quoteLineItems;
```

Comment: I did that and it stopped returning records, is there an update I should be making to my SOQL query in the apex class as well? The Quote_ID__c is supposed to be in there it was a custom field I made to get the 18 digit ID

Comment: This could be my bad, JS is case sensitive and I had camel cased the wired property. Other checks you could do is log `this.recordId` in renderedCallback to see if the recordId is binded correctly. The apex method looks ok, but might be worth writing a test method for it if you haven't already to see if the data comes back as expected.